# Trying to set up views under each other programatically in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my fragment's onCreateView method I'm trying to programatically inflate viewstubs to layouts under each other, but the first two takes place inside each other, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTq7H.png)

Here is my fragment's onCreateView method

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   mBaseLayout = (PercentRelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calender, container, false);
    findViews();
    mBundle = new Bundle();

    mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    mDaysContainer = (RelativeLayout) mBaseLayout.findViewById(R.id.daysContainer);



    mStartPeriod = DateAndTime.getFirstDayFirstWeekOfMonthAsString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    mEndPeriod = DateAndTime.getLastDayLastWeekOfMonthAsString("yyyy-MM-dd");

    mPeriodTextView.setText(mStartPeriod + " - " + mEndPeriod);

    createDayFragments(); // Create the fragments
    findDayViewIds();     // Get access to the views

    return mBaseLayout;
}
```

I use this method to create the views and put them into the container

```
 private void createDayFragments() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        mFragments.add(new ViewStub(getActivity()));
        mFragments.get(i).setId(i);
        mDaysContainer.addView(mFragments.get(i));
        ViewStub viewStub = (ViewStub) mBaseLayout.findViewById(i);
        viewStub.setInflatedId(i);
        viewStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.fragment_day);
        Log.d("ID", mFragments.get(i).getId() + "");
        Log.d("i = ", i + "");

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        if(i >= 1){
            p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i - 1);
            Log.d("Below ID", i - 1 + "");
        }


        viewStub.setLayoutParams(p);

        Log.d("", "");
        viewStub.inflate();
    }
}
```

And I use this method to get access to all the views after creating them

```
  private void findDayViewIds(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        RelativeLayout tmpRel = (RelativeLayout) mDaysContainer.findViewById(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < tmpRel.getChildCount(); ++j){
            if(tmpRel.getChildAt(j) instanceof PercentRelativeLayout) {
                PercentRelativeLayout percentTmp = (PercentRelativeLayout) tmpRel.getChildAt(j);
                percentTmp.setId(100 + i);
                for(int h = 0; h < percentTmp.getChildCount(); ++h){
                    if(percentTmp.getChildAt(h) instanceof TextView){
                        TextView textViewTmp = (TextView) percentTmp.getChildAt(h);
                        textViewTmp.setId(300 + i);
                        textViewTmp.setText("Day " + i + " ID: " + tmpRel.getId());
                    }
                }
            } else if (tmpRel.getChildAt(j) instanceof ViewStub){
                tmpRel.getChildAt(j).setId(200 + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the XML for the fragment that should contain the other fragments

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/weekDisplayed">

<TextView
    android:text="Placeholder"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_heightPercent="10%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="94%"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/datefrom_dateto_bottom_border"
    android:id="@+id/periodTextView"/>


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        app:layout_widthPercent="94%"
        android:layout_below="@+id/periodTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:layout_marginBottomPercent="4%"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout <!-- This is where i want the fragments -->
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/daysContainer">

        </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

And here is the xml for the fragment I want to inflate into my daysContainer relative layout

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">



 <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/dayContainerOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


        <TextView
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="2%"
            android:text="placeholder"
            android:id="@+id/weekOneTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:typeface="monospace"/>

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

    <ViewStub layout="@layout/fragment_replace"
              android:id="@+id/replaceOne"
              android:layout_below="@id/dayContainerOne"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    </ViewStub>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try shifting `ids` up by `1`. So your first `id` is not equal to 0. My guess is that `BELOW` doesn't work if given `id` equals `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try shifting `ids` up by `1`. So your first `id` is not equal to `0`. My guess is that `BELOW` doesn't work if given `id` equals `0`.

**Update to my comment.**

Found the following line in `RelativeLayout` sources:

`rules[BELOW] = a.getResourceId(attr, 0);`

Where `0` is the default value, therefore it is ignored.